# org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'text' is not present

Tags: java, jquery, spring-boot

I am trying to send a string and an image from the view to the controller, but I keep getting this error:

> String parameter'text' is not present

I tried some of the solutions that I found online, but none of them solved my issue.

```js
 @RequestMapping(value = "/post-create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        @ResponseBody
        public String[][] createPost(@RequestParam(value="text" ) String text,
                                 @RequestParam(value = "photo") MultipartFile body) throws IOException {
            User user = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
            String username = user.getUsername();
            com.project.agro.entities.User user1 = userService.getUserByUsername(username);

            Image image = new Image(body.getBytes());
            imageService.addImage(image);
            Post post = new Post();
            post.setAuthor(user1);
            post.setText(text);
            post.setImage(image);
            postService.addPost(post);

            post = postService.addPost(post);
            List<Post> posts = new ArrayList<>();
            posts.add(post);

            return utilsService.arrayFill(posts, user1);
        }
```

JQuery

```
 $("#create-post-button").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $('form')[0];
        var formData = new FormData(form);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/post-create',
            data: formData,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#posts-container").prepend(concatPost(data[0]));
                $("#special-alert").remove();
                $("#posts-container").append('' + special_alert_no_more_posts);
                document.getElementById('create-post-form').reset();
                $("#characters-number").text(5000);
                from += 1;
                $("#create-post-button").prop("disabled", true);
            }
        })

    });
```

HTML

```
<div id="create-post-box" class="row">
  <hr class=\ "middle\">
  <a id="create-post-box-href"><span id="arrow-down"
                            class="fa fa-angle-down"></span><span id="arrow-up"
                            class="fa fa-angle-up hidden"></span></a>
  <div id="create-post-form-div" class="hidden">
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="create-post-form" method="POST">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <textarea class="form-control" maxlength="5000" rows="5" id="post-text" name="text"></textarea>
          <div id="counter">
            <p id="counter-line">
              <span id="characters-number">5000</span> symbols left.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="input-group">
            <label class="input-group-btn"> <span class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></span><input id="file" type="file" style="display: none;" name="photo" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg" multiple>
   </span>
   </label> <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <button type="button" id="create-post-button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md btn-block">Post it</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

I tried

```
@RequestParam(value="text" ,required=false)
```

but then it shows:

> String parameter'photo' is not present with Multipart
>   missingservletexception

Answer (score 0):

Try using `@RequestBody MultipartFile body` instead of `@RequestParam(value = "photo") MultipartFile body`

Comment: I tried doing that as well .It shows Required request body is missing

Comment: Did you try to debug and see if your request passed through inside your java code? That's really what is needed from java side... Also would be helpful if you check the execution/response in browser developer console "Network" tab when you press the submit button on the form

Comment: I did look at console in my browser and it shows smthg like this                                jquery.min.js:4 POST http://localhost:8080/post-create 400
send @ jquery.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ userpage-posts.js:52
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
q.handle @ jquery.min.js:3